# How to bind click event to element hasn't specific child using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I have several elements on a page like bottom code.

```
<div>
   <a href="#" id="notme">click</a>
   some content 
</div>
```

They can be clicked and jQuery picks that click. However one of the elements has a `a` link that is clicked should not be picked as a click of the parent element.

```
$('div:not(#notme)').on('click', function(e) {
    // do something
});
```

Doesn't seem to work for some reason...

Comment: [It work](https://jsfiddle.net/5tppgpg4/). You need to change `$('div:not(#notme)')` to `$('a:not(#notme)')`.

Comment: I need to register an event when div is clicked, but not when the link within that div. It is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`:has`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector to selecting div element has specific child. In `:has` use [`:not`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

```js
$("div:has(a:not(#notme))").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <a href="#" id="notme">click</a>
   some content 
</div>
<div>
   <a href="#" >click2</a>
   some content 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
$('div').on('click', function(e) {
  if($(e.target).attr("id") !== "notme") {
    // do something
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#notme').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I have no idea if it's helping him or not since he hasn't commented on anyone's answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's a canned comment I put on otherwise decent answers when I see them in the low quality queue. Also it's about more than just this OP, right? :)